# How do I make an OpenVPN server access the internet using its second IPv4 when a client connects to VPN on a specific port?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

Here are my current environment details for clarification:

Platform: Linux VPS

OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04

Firewall: UFW

I have deployed an OpenVPN server on a Linux VPS. the VPN server works perfectly on both UDP and TCP protocols. the server has had a single IPv4 address which I call it `IP1` for reference here. whenever I connect to my VPN on my client machines. my client IP address becomes the `IP1` which is totally perfect.

BUT, now I have assigned a second IPv4 to my VPS which I call it `IP2` for reference here.

the network interfaces of my server are like this now:

1. eth0 → IP1
2. eth0:1 → IP2

I’ve setup three instances of OpenVPN on my VPS with these configs:

1. 10.8.0.0 → IP1 -> 1194 (UDP)
2. 10.8.1.0 → IP1 -> 443 (TCP)
3. 10.8.2.0 → IP2 -> 1195 (UDP)

I’ve also added these rules into `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file:

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2

and everything works fine and I can connect to VPN on all three ports, But the issue is that when I connect on port `1195` which is configured to route to `IP2`, my client still gets the `IP1` from the server and when I check my IP it shows me `IP1`.

I want to know what should I do to be able to configure the server to access the public internet using the `IP2` when a client connects to VPN on port `1195`?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE -
the full output of `iptables-save -t nat`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Jun 28 14:26:28 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:40]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0:1 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0:1 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0:1 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 28 14:26:28 2022
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/24` instead of `/8` in the `-s` matches of your `SNAT` rules.

FINAL TOUCH:

after changing the rules try `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING` and restart the ufw, and check with `iptables-save -t nat` after that to make sure there are no other conflicting `SNAT / MASQUERADE` rules.

Comment: I did it, but still the same, I get `IP1` when I connect to VPN on port `1195`. any further idea? should I define new iptables for it to work? as mentioned here: [Linux Advanced Routing And Traffic Control HOWTO](https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html)

Comment: Add the FULL output of `iptables-save -t nat` to your question. (`IP1` and `IP2` can remain redacted if you wish.)

Comment: I've added the result, please take a look.

Comment: Try `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING` before you / and restart the ufw, and check again with `iptables-save -t nat` after that to make sure there are no other conflicting `SNAT` / `MASQUERADE` rules.

Comment: Wow, thank you dear Tom, you saved my life indeed. I was struggling for a week. it worked after executing `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING` and all intervening rules got removed.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted and edited it to include your last suggestion.